# Is there a way get info from the indexing of an old vector when creating a new vector from it

Tags: r

Let's say I have a vector named `ages` and I bound the values of a vector to a limit:

```
# Create vector
ages <- c(1:7427) # This is not what my vector is actually assigned as btw, it has a lot of random floats in reality.

# Set limits
min_HB <- 11.68987
max_HB <- 11.81083

# Limit vector
HB_ages <- sapply(ages, function(y) min(max(y,min_HB),max_HB))
```

The `HB_ages` range is from `1` to `length(HB_ages)`, but I would still like to get info on what are the indices of the values from the original vector. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps you need `stack(setNames(HB_ages, ages))`.  Also, this can be vectorized with `pmin(pmax(ages, min_HB), max_HB)`

Comment: Small correction: `HB_ages`'s "range" is from `min_HB` to `max_HB`. Its indexes span from `1` to `length(ages)`, R is a 1-based array programming language. To your question *"indices of the values from the original vector"*, the order has not changed, so the indices of `HB_ages` onto `ages` is merely `seq_along(ages)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `stack` on a named `vector`

```
stack(setNames(HB_ages, ages))
```

Or with vectorized approach

```
data.frame(ind = ages, val = pmin(pmax(ages, min_HB), max_HB))
```

Comment: `stack(setNames(HB_ages, ages))` aligns the values of `HB_ages` with the values of `ages`, but I want to match each value of `HB_ages` with the index of the same value in the `ages` vector.

Comment: @Woj here the index is the same as 'ages' because it is a sequence from  1 to 7427

Comment: So if, for example, the value of `HB_ages[1]`, which is at the first index of `HB_ages`, was the 1390 index in `ages`, how would I confirm this? (i.e. how do I extract the `ages` index of `HB_ages` values from your `stack` suggestion?)

Comment: @Woj In your `HB_ages` there are only two unique values.  It is not clear `unique(HB_ages)#
[1] 11.68987 11.81083`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a very simple problem to me. Correct me if I am wrong.

Here is your ages vector (slightly modified)

```
ages <- round(rnorm(100, 32, 15))
ages
  [1] 37 31  2 33 15 20 41 38 71 47 50 40 64 32 54 28 62 38 42 24 39 22 32 29
 [25] 26 27 32 50 33 11 22 15 21  5 43 17 45 51 47 54 15 13 21 29 13 21 33 23
 [49] 40 24 20 36 29 35 42 54 30 53 32 48 39 46 20 62 49 41 35 44 50 56 17 43
 [73] 36 22 38 30 19 14 40 26 27 50 36 32 36 51 41 25 58 45 27 45 30 44  9 29
 [97] 43 19 41  5
```

and here are your limits:

```
min_HB <- 11.68987
max_HB <- 11.81083
```

and this is what you have done:

```
HB_ages <- sapply(ages, function(y) min(max(y,min_HB),max_HB))
```

Index is the same order of the values. Just add that order.

```
cbind(HB_ages, c(1:length(HB_ages)))
```

The second column is what you need. Correct?